# Choosing One vs All and One vs One for Multiclass SVM

Tags: svm, multiclass-classification

What consideration do I need to take when choosing between One vs All or One vs One algorithm for Multiclass SVM?

Answer (score 1):

The main consideration is the number of classes, assume you have $N$ different classes: "one vs all" will train one classifier per class, so $N$ classifiers in total. For a given class $c_i$ the classifier assumes samples with $c_i$ as positives and the rest as negatives. Obviously, this leads to imbalanced datasets, moreover, in "one vs all" [the outputs must be calibrated to produce comparable results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143152/why-do-one-versus-all-multi-class-svms-need-to-be-calibrated/143563).

In "one vs one" you train a separate classifier for each different pair of classes, so $\frac{N(N - 1)}{2}$, obviously this is computationally expensive.

For more details see this: [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91091/one-vs-all-and-one-vs-one-in-svm) and [2](https://www.quora.com/In-multi-class-classification-what-are-pros-and-cons-of-One-to-Rest-and-One-to-One).